# Eloquera DB on Windows Phone 7 / WP7?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, windows-phone-7, eloquera

Has anyone tried using Eloquera DB on WP7?  Besides the question of whether it actually works under WP7, how is the performance (if it actually works)?  Are there alrernative object-based DBs that anyone can recommend for use with WP7 applications?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't explored or used Eloquera DB on Windows Phone 7 (Do they have WP7 version?). However, I have extensively used [Windows Phone 7 DB](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/) as well as the [Windows Phone 7 SQLite wrapper](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/07/wp7-sqliteclient-with-transaction.html), and, I found both work great. I use Windows Phone 7 DB for most of my applications.

HTH, indyfromoz

Answer (score 1):

Looking on their site, Eloquera supports .NET 3.5 & 4, but no Silverlight, which is what WP7 runs, so I'd say it's no go.

Indyfromoz's suggestions look quite promising, and there's also [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) and [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst).

Answer (score 0):

For windows phone 7 I would go with [Sterling DB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/)